# Why do char functions require becoming a pointer when returning a string?

Tags: c, pointers

I am a beginner C programmer and I am having difficulties grasping the concept of pointers. My question is why does the program require `char *lowercase` to run normally and why, if I remove the `*`, it breaks the program?

```
char *lowercase(char a[]){
int c = 0;
char *lowercase_string = malloc(300);
strcpy(lowercase_string,a);
while (lowercase_string[c] != '\0') {
    if( lowercase_string[c] >= 'A' && lowercase_string[c] <= 'Z' ){
        lowercase_string[c] = lowercase_string[c]+32;
    }
    c++;
 }
 return lowercase_string;
 }
```

Comment: If you remove the `*` you get a function returning one single character. How would you return a string then?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say and now I realize it was kind of a dumb question but thanks a lot for helping me out. Have a good day!

Comment: Don't worry. That's part of learning. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, strings are just contiguous chunks of characters, ending with a null byte (the character with a value of 0, denoted by `'\0'` or `'\x00'`). To represent a string, a **pointer** to the first element is used, which is what the star means after char. When you return a pointer, you return **where** the string is, and people can use that information to get the whole string just by iterating (by adding to the pointer/looking past it) until they find a null byte. If you just return `char`, you only can return one character of the string, which is nowhere close to the full string.

Comment: I think you can emphasize that pointer returns memory address (of the characters sequence), while char is actually a value.

Comment: Now, that you explained it, it makes a lot more sense. Thanks a lot and have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

As written is previous answers, the char pointer points to the first letter of the string, which gives you the ability to scan the whole string (moving 1 char at a time).

Additionally, since your string is allocated on the heap, it must be accessed through a pointer, as the allocated block of memory is nameless.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the issue is how C treats arrays (not just arrays of character type, but any type).

Arrays are not pointers - they are contiguous sequences of objects of some type.  No pointer is part of the array object itself.  When you declare an array like `int arr[5];`, you get something like this in memory:

```
     +–––+
arr: |   | arr[0]
     +–––+
     |   | arr[1]
     +–––+
      ...
     +–––+
     |   | arr[4]
     +–––+
```

However, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you pass an array argument to a function, what the function actually receives is a pointer to the first element.  When you attempt to return an array from a function, that array expression will be converted to a pointer (more on this later).  In fact, you cannot declare a function to return an array type - something like

```
int foo( void )[10];
```

is not allowed.  You can return pointers to arrays:

```
int (*foo( void ))[10];
```

but not arrays directly.  This is why the `*alloc` functions return pointers instead of array types.

This is also why returning non-`static` local arrays from a function is a problem - you’re not returning the *value* of the array (that is, a copy of the array’s contents), you’re returning its address.  After the function returns, though, that array no longer exists and that pointer value is *invalid*.  That’s why you need to use `malloc` to allocate storage that will hang around after the function returns.

Strings are sequences of character values including a zero-valued terminator.  The string `"hello"` is represented by the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l’, 'o', 0}`.  Strings (including string literals) are stored in arrays of character type (`char` for ASCII, EBCDIC, and UTF-8 encodings, `wchar_t` for "wide" encodings like UTF-16).

So, that’s all background.  In your specific case, you need to declare `lowercase` as `char *` because it is returning a value of that type (`lowercase_string`).  It breaks when you leave the `*` off because you’re telling the rest of the program it returns a *single* character value, not a pointer, and the rest of the program is expecting it to return a pointer.

Answer (score -2):

Your program is returning a pointer so you must call the function with char *.

And you know, in c a char array is also treated as a char pointer

Comment: No, char arrays are not treated as pointers, that is a broad simplification, which is usally wrong.